# WCF Express Interop Bindings for visual studio 2013

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

Isn't WCF Express Interop Bindings template available for Visual Studio 2013? If available, please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support Visual studio 2013. Please check the below installation steps..

[WCF Express Interop Bindings Walk Through](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings%20Walk%20Through)
**Installation:**

1. Download the Visual Studio Extension file from [here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/68276).
2. Double click on the extension and chose install
3. The extension is supported on **Visual Studio 2010 Standard and greater**.
4. If you had Visual Studio 2010 open, close it and re-open it.
5. You can verify the installation by checking your Extension Manager in the tools menu.

**Pre-requisites**

- .NET 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010 Standard edition or above (Express is not supported)
- WCF 4.0
- Visual Studio 2010 SDK (necessary to build the source)
      [Download Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en)
      Download Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK

I have VS2010 and VS2013 both installed but this plugin installer only asking to install this plugin in VS2010. check the below image:

[image]